# problems with Samba share

Tags: samba

I run Samba on my Debian NAS and have two problems. Samba run fine and I can upload and download files without any problems.

The first problem:

I have a folder `/mnt/disk/public/JDownloads/` in that folder are files downloaded by JDownloader. But some of them are not visable when I watch in that folder from Windows or any Samba client!

Jdownloader downloaded the files in that folder by user jdownloader and group jdownloader.

Why I can not see all files?

And the second problem is:

In that folder also are some Directorys created by JDownloader but I can not delete that folder from Windows explorer!

I have tried to solve the first problem by force samba connections to be root by (I think root can read and write all file no metter wich user):

```
force group = root
force user = root
```

And the second problem with:

```
delete readonly = yes
```

but no success. please help

Here is my conf for this share:

```
path = /mnt/disk/public
read only = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
delete readonly = yes
valid users = root jdownloader
force group = root
force user = root
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Linux users are stored in `/etc/passwd`, samba users are stored in `/etc/samba/smbpasswd`

It's not true that all linux users automatically, have access to samba
You have to add samba users with the command `smbpasswd`.

Have you tried to add the jdownloader user to samba with

```
smbpasswd -a jdownloader
```

and from client-side to login as user jdownloader? (restart smb daemon, connection with new credentials)

---

As a quick & dirty solution you might use these global settings

```
force create mode = 777
force directory mode = 777
force security mode = 777
force directory security mode = 777
```